# Custom type resolution

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have assembly A which has a reference to type T in another assembly B. But at runtime this assembly doesn't have that type, so I get `TypeLoadException`.

Is there any way to load T from my assembly without **(!)** recompilation of A or B?

Runtime doesn't call `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` nor `AppDomain.TypeResolve` for such case.
I'm searching for managed solution (any runtime flavor) and without IL rewrite.

*Note: this is not X Y problem.*

Comment: I've previously used the Roslyn Compiler to dynamically create types at runtime - maybe helps you out here?

Comment: Can you provide your code producing the exception?

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin exception is raised when calling method that references missing type. Assembly A is compiled against ref assembly where this type is defined, at runtime type is missing in assembly.